# How to destroy session ("logout") with token-authenticated users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

For Devise user models that use `:token_authenticatable`, like so

```
class Voter < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :token_authenticatable
end
```

there used to be a route called `destroy_user_session`, so that you could log users out by linking to `destroy_user_session_path`. This seems to have changed in recent versions -- now only `:database_authenticatable` creates a destroy route for me.

So for users that use token authentication, what is the proper way to implement a "log out"/"sign out" action to end their sessions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[By default](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/token_authenticatable.rb#L27), when you sign in via token, Devise will store the user in session just like in the database authentication strategy.

You can disable this by setting `stateless_token` to `true` in the Devise initializer:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.stateless_token = true
end
```

This way, the token must be provided with *every request*.

---

As I understand it, token authentication was designed to be used together with database authentication. `devise_for` will only add the session routes if your model is `database_authenticatable`. This seems like a minor oversight on Devise's part, but in my opinion, access tokens leaving the user in session doesn't make much sense to me to begin with.

Anyway, try to define the routes to Devise's sessions manually.

Adapted from [Devise's routing helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L291) (untested code):

```
as :user do  # User scope
  resource :session, :controller => 'devise/sessions' do
    # new_user_session | GET /users/sign_in => devise/sessions#new
    get :new, :path => 'sign_in', :as => "new"

    # user_session | POST /users/sign_in => devise/sessions#create
    post :create, :path => 'sign_in'

    # destroy_user_session | GET /users/sign_out => devise/sessions#destroy
    get :destroy, :path => 'sign_out', :as => "destroy"
  end
end
```

In any case, [the documentation for the `devise_for` helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L27) specifies which routes are created and what they point to.

Comment: Hey Matheus, thanks for the pointer. I think I actually like the user session being stored, rather than carrying the token along with every request. My question is more along the lines of, if I *don't* use stateless token auth, how do I log the user out at the end? IOW, how do I end the session that Devise stores for me?

Comment: How did you learn these things btw? Did you read the RDocs, or did you just go straight for the source?

Comment: @Jo, updated answer. I learned about stateless tokens while configuring Devise for my own projects. I always read the docs first. I only go for source when the documentation doesn't have what I want to know, or when I need to understand how things work. (It's helpful when I need to answer questions, such as this one! :P) While it is helpful to understand the inner workings, it's not always possible or realistic (Rails's codebase, for example, is huge), so always go for the documentation, articles, tutorials, whatever you can find, first.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. The code you posted gives you `destroy_session_path` instead of `destroy_user_session_path`, and `/session/sign_out` instead of `/user/sign_out`, and I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to get both of these right inside a `resource` block, but here is my sign_out route, which signs out the user as desired (at `destroy_user_session_path` and `user/sign_out`): https://gist.github.com/356b11c76655331b9443 It uses GET like your example  -- I think Devise's default might be DELETE, but IMHO that's unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: And I just discovered that instead of using a `devise_scope` a.k.a. `as` block, you can just put it inside the block of `devise_for :users`.